# Proof to an observation of stabilisers and orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> Observation:
>
> If $\alpha^{g}=\beta$ then $G_{\beta}=g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$

Just to get the notation out of the way:

$G_{\beta}= g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is the stabiliser of a point element $\beta$ in a permutation group G of a finite set $\Omega$.

The notation is a bit odd but it is what it is when your professor is an Algebraist.

We need to show $G_{\beta} \subseteq  g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ and  $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g \subseteq G_{\beta}$.
Once we do, we are done with the proof.

I will seek help with the latter. Once I understand the argument I will be able to figure out the former.

> Proof:
>
> $g^{-1}: \alpha^{g}=\beta \rightarrow \alpha =  \beta^{g^{-1}}$
>
> $G_{\alpha}:\alpha=\beta^{g^{-1}}:$ fixes $\alpha$
>
> $g:\alpha=\beta^{g^{-1}}\rightarrow \alpha^{g}=\beta$

Indeed, $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g:\alpha^{g}=\beta\rightarrow \alpha^{g}=\beta$

> Hence,
>
> $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g \subseteq G_{\beta}$

I believe my lack of understanding comes from something more fundamental. To be clear, every line of the argument is understandable but come the conclusion, I am unable to understand how it relates. Say, how is $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ a set and in particular how is it a set of the set $G_{\beta}.$

Would any kind gentleman provide some insights?

Comment: I understand now $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is in the set of $G_{\beta}$ but I can't yet understand how $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a set.

Comment: $g^{-1}G_\alpha g$ is a subgroup. It is also a set ( I suppose since maybe all groups are, or can be), but it is not a subset of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume $G$ is acting on some set $\Omega$, and for any element $\alpha \in \Omega$, the notation $\alpha^g$ means the image of $\alpha$ under this action, which is also often written as $\alpha \cdot g$.

$G_{\alpha}$ denotes, by definition, the set of elements of $g$ which fix $\alpha$, so $g \in G_{\alpha}$ if and only if $\alpha^g = \alpha$. It is easy to check that $G_{\alpha}$ is a subgroup of $G$. It is called the stabilizer of $\alpha$ in $G$.

For any subgroup $H \leq G$, the set $g^{-1}Hg = \{g^{-1}hg : h \in H\}$ is also a subgroup. Again this is easy to check. So $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a subgroup of $G$. The purpose of this problem is to show that $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is in fact the stabilizer of the element $\alpha^g$.

Restating your argument to make it a bit easier to follow, suppose that $h \in g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$. Then $h = g^{-1}kg$ for some $k \in G_{\alpha}$, so $k$ has the property that $\alpha^k = \alpha$. Now let us see what happens to $\beta = \alpha^g$ when $h$ acts on it:
$$(\alpha^g)^h = \alpha^{gh} = \alpha^{g(g^{-1}kg)} = \alpha^{kg} = (\alpha^k)^g = \alpha^g$$
This shows that $h$ indeed stabilizes $\alpha^g$. Since $h$ was an arbitrary element of $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$, we have shown that
$$g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g \subseteq G_{\beta}$$
Showing the opposite containment is quite similar.

Comment: The statement is true for group actions in general, not just by conjugation. I wouldn't assume they mean the action is by conjugation unless it says so, especially since it is less general to assume so.

Comment: I assumed that $\alpha^g=\beta$ meant that $g \cdot \alpha = \beta$ (to use sane notation), and that the question was about group actions in general.

Comment: @TaiyoTerada OK fair enough, usually I have seen $\alpha^g$ to denote $g^{-1}\alpha g$ but maybe it is really $\alpha \cdot g$ under some generic group action. Let me edit accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, I would assume it is what @stochasm said. I prefer acting on the right like the asker used, but it is equivalent $g\cdot \alpha$

Comment: @TaiyoTerada Yes, I assumed from the context that the action is on the right, so $\alpha^{gh} = (\alpha^{g})^h$ instead of $(\alpha^{h})^g$.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks a lot. I think I get it.
On an intuitivel level, the way I understand $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a set is  that

$ g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g=\left \{g^{-1}k_{i}g|k_{i} \in G_{\alpha}, \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}\right \}$.

 Is this valid?
Essentially, I am only concern that 

$g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is some element that fixes my initial point element.

Comment: @Mathematicing Almost correct, except you shouldn't assume that $G_{\alpha}$ can be indexed by $\mathbb Z$ since it may be finite, or it may be uncountable. Better simply to write $g^{-1}G_{\alpha} g = \{g^{-1} k g \mid k \in G_{\alpha}\}$.

Comment: Noted. Cheers! @Bungo

Comment: @Mathematicing Think of the action by an element of $g^{-1} G_{\alpha} g$ as three stages: first $g^{-1}$ acts, which moves $\alpha^g$ to $(\alpha^{g})^{g^{-1} }= \alpha$. Then some arbitrary element of $G_\alpha$ acts, which leaves $\alpha$ unchanged. Then $g$ acts, which moves $\alpha$ back to $\alpha^g$.

Comment: I actually had that figured out. In the OP,$ g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a map from a some point element to the same point element. By definition,  $ g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a stabiliser of a point.
To see that $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a set I relied on my previously mentioned intuition to see that $g^{-1}G_{\alpha}g$ is a collection of elements.

Comment: @Mathematicing It is more than a set, it is a subgroup of $G$. The fact that it is a set is obvious, since by definition it is the set of all elements of the form $g^{-1}ag$ with $a \in G_\alpha$.

Comment: I will prove that it is a subgroup of G in an exercise. Thanks. I really like this answer.